# Magento 2, issue with forgotpassword.phtml template override

Tags: magento2, customer, custom-template

In my custom module I have created `app/code/myVendor/myModule/view/frontend/layout/customer_account_forgotpassword.xml` . With below content I can see title is changing but form gets disappear instead of displaying the content in `forgotpassword.phtml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<head>
    <title>From my module</title>
</head>
<body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Forgotpassword" name="forgotPassword" template="myVendor_myModule::form/forgotpassword.phtml">
            <container name="form.additional.info" as="form_additional_info"/>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

I have done upgrading, compiling, deploying and emptied the cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code under `<body>` tag of your xml file

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
     <referenceBlock name="forgotPassword">
         <action method="setTemplate">
             <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">myVendor_myModule::form/forgotpassword.phtml</argument>
         </action>
     </referenceBlock>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: I did, but No luck :(

Comment: it should work , please confirm your template path and Namespace_Module name